# No-cache and cookies issue

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm creating a small store and using cookies to store bought items.
When an item is added to cart I do something like:

```
document.cookie="itemname=added";
```

Then I have a button to go to cart and in php I do:

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $cookie=>$value)
{
    if ($value=="added")
          ...something
}
```

Everything works except than I need to reload the page for the items to show in the cart. It also work if I add a `?u=randomvalue` to cart links but it's very annoying for some reasons.

This is my html header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<title>Shop</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

</head>
```

Is there something I'm forgetting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add php headers like that:

```
<?
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```